# Wrapping/Merging 2 divs together

Tags: css

I have two divs, a `#sidebar` on the left and a #main for listing images. The height of the #sidebar is shorter than the height of `#main`, and I would like for the content/images in #main to go under the `#sidebar` once it ends.

Here are the current css code:

```
.user #sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 210px;
}

.user #main {
    float: right;
    width:728px;
}
```

Here's an image showing the condition of my page and the what I would like to do:

[image]

Comment: Just remove `float:right` and `width` from `.user #main`

Answer (score 0):

Just put `sidebar` inside `main` and use `float: left` on the `sidebar`.  Remove the `float: right` and `width` from `main`, and just let it be 100% width.  The images should appear next to sidebar until they can be displayed under it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use three divs above the `#main` div:

```
.user #main {
    float: right;
    width:728px;
}
user #sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 210px;
    height:h px;
}
user #sidebar2 {
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:210px;
    width: 518px;
    height:h px;
}
user #sidebar3 {
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:210px;
    width: 728px;
}
```